# Internal SD card reader - Acer Aspire 1410, Lub 16.04

Tags: sd-card

Trying to get an internal SD card reader working under Lubuntu 16.04. Acer Aspire 1410, card reader is Alcor AU6433, on USB port 3 in Acer documentation.

Card reader does NOT appear in `lsusb` when there is no card inserted.
It DOES appear when card is inserted, as:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 058f:6366 Alcore Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
```

Output of `dmesg -w` when card inserted.

```
[ 2792.104058] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci.  
[ 2792.253487] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6366.  
[ 2792.253492] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3.  
[ 2792.253495] usb 2-4: Product: Mass Storage Device.  
[ 2792.253497] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Generic.  
[ 2792.253500] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 058F63666433.  
[ 2792.255692] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected.  
[ 2792.258353] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-4:1.0.  
[ 2793.408907] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Multiple Card Reader     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0.  
[ 2793.412952] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0.  
[ 2793.792643] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk.
```

When card removed:.

```
[ 2894.094634] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 13
```

In Dash>Accessories>Disks: 
The reader appears when card inserted, with the correct serial number. However it shows "No Media" in the "Volumes" window.

The card is 2GB, and works in other computers.  I've blown out the slot and examined physical contacts - nothing obviously wrong.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Muliti-card reader will not display in the device list if no memory card is plugged in. This is normal behavior. Since your sdcard works in other computers and dmesg reports correct operation, It is most likely a bad slot in your laptop.

Comment: Thanks much for looking at it and commenting.  Your 2 statements that the device list behavior and the dmesg reports are normal and correct are VERY valuable just in and of themselves.  Since this is my first encounter with drive tools and dmesg I did not know if what I was looking at was normal or not.